# Firestore call extremely slow - how to make it faster?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm migrating from MongoDB to Firestore and I've been struggling to make this call faster. So, to give you the context, this is how every document looks like in the collection:

Document sample:

[image]
The **"entities"** object may have the following fields: **"customer"**, **"supplier"**, **"product"**, **"product_group"** and/or **"origin"**. What I'm trying to do is to build a ranking, e.g., **a supplier ranking for docs with origin = "A" and product = "B"**. That means, I have to get from the DB all documents with **entities = { origin:"A", product:"B", supplier: *exists* }**

The collection has more than 300.000 documents, and I make between 4-10 calls depending on the "entities", which return between 0 and a few hundred results each. These calls are taking excessively long to execute (between 10 and 30 seconds in total) in Firestore, whereas with MongoDB it took around 2-3 seconds in total. This is how my code looks like as of now (following the previous example, the parameters in the function would be **entities = {origin:"A", product:"B"}** and **entity = "supplier"**):

```
async getRanking(entities: { [key: string]: any }, stage: string, metric: string, organisationId: string, entity: string) {
        let indicators: IndicatorInsight[] = [];    
        const entitySet = ['product', 'origin', 'product_group', 'supplier', 'customer'];

        const entitiesKeys = []; 
        //this way we always keep the values in the same order as in entitySet
        for (const ent of entitySet) {
            if ([...Object.keys(entities), entity].includes(ent)) {
                entitiesKeys.push(ent);
            }
        }

        let rankingRef = OrganisationRef
            .doc(organisationId)
            .collection('insight')
            .where('stage', '==', stage)
            .where('metric', '==', metric)          
            .where('insight_type', '==', 'indicator')           
            .where('entities_keys', '==', entitiesKeys)

        for (const ent of Object.keys(entities)) {
            rankingRef = rankingRef.where(`entities.${ent}`, '==', entities[ent]);          
        }
        
        (await rankingRef.get()).forEach(snap => indicators.push(snap.data() as IndicatorInsight));

        return indicators;
    }
```

So my question is, do you have any suggestion on how to improve the structure of the documents and the querying in order to improve the performance of this call?  As I mentioned, with MongoDB this was quite fast, 2-3 seconds tops.

I've been told Firestore should be extremely fast, so I guess I'm not doing things right here and I'd really appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I don't immediately see where the performance problem would come from. One thing you might want to try is to see if performance improves if you [create a composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) for one of the combinations of fields. If that improves matters for that specific, at least you'll know it's related to the number of indexes it needs to consider.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your answer. I already created composite indexes for the most important combinations but that didn't help either. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm tinkering with some settings and I realized that if I turn off persistence I don't have this problem anymore, it really flies now. Could that be the problem? If so, why? Sadly this is not an option for us, since enablePersistence() is a must for this app.

Comment: That was going to be my next question. :)  Did you insert the data from the same device where you're testing the query performance? If so, please wipe the local storage for that app, or uninstall/reinstall on iOS/Android. The local cache does not have the same performance guarantees as the server. Usually this isn't a problem, since the cache is auto-cleaned. But any data that is *written* from the device seems to persist in the local cache, which means it skews results if you have a single device that inserted the majority of your data.

Comment: I even deployed the app and opened it from a different computer but it didn't solve the issue. This particular part of the app doesn't use the offline persistence btw, could it be a solution to create a second instance of firebase/firestore without persistence and use it in this section of the app? That would mean that the user would have to authenticate twice though.

Comment: How many documents do you pull into the local cache? It really should not cause performance issues, except in edge cases like the one I described above. Also: any way you can set this same problem up in a place where I can have a look at it? Something like jsbin or stackblitz would be really useful, so I can poke (and possibly point some team mates) at it.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I really appreciate your help. Sadly I can't share anything related to the app, since we are under NDA and there's a lot of private data from our client in the DB. Anyway, we found a workaround for this problem: I'm now using a callable function to fetch the data and, while the performance is not as good as when we call it directly from inside the app without persistence, it's still within acceptable range and a lot better than before.

Comment: Good to hear you found a workaround.  I still don't understand what is happening to cause this behavior, so if you ever reproduce it in an isolated environment I'd love to take a look.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I really appreciate it. I'll let you know when I set up an environment with dummy data for you to look into it, but for now we are kind of in a hurry and we have to move forward with the app :)